# Make npm work in tails

Tags: node.js, tor, npm, tails-os

The latest tails comes with nodejs v10.24.0. Trying to get tails to run a newer node has been unsuccessful even after running script from deb.nodesource.com/setup_14x which said buster was unsupported. I think updating node was a red herring anyway.

npm is not included so I use

`sudo apt install npm`

to install npm. I get version 5.8.0. I need npm to install create-react-app and other node tools.
All npm commands return warning

Npm does not support node.js v10.24.0

(hence the red herring to update that)

In persistant storage I create a directory "foo" and cd to foo, I run

`npm init`

And then

`npm install`

And in addition to the warning above it seems to fail to connect to

registry.npmjs.org:443

with getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Putting that url into the tor browser connects just fine.
My current working theory is that I need to configure npm proxy and npm https-proxy, but for that I seem to require proxy credentials, url, and port. I don't know what those are or how to find them in tails. I am not behind any other proxy besides tor running in Tails.

Question: how to make npm work in tails.

Comment: The settings should be SOCKS (or SOCKS5) as protocol, localhost as the host name and 9050 as the port.  More details here https://miloserdov.org/?p=2640

Comment: Or better option - use proxychains: `sudo apt install proxychains dnsutils` and then `proxychains npm init` and `proxychains npm install`